# Unpublished sitecore items not removed from solr index

Tags: search, solr, sitecore9

When I unpublish a sitecore item it's not being removed from our custom solr index. We're using `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.SxaItemCrawler` for our crawler type, and the version of `sitecore` is `9.0.2` (rev. 180604)

I have confirmed in the event table that the deleteitemremote and publishendremote events are being created.

Updates and additions work fine, it's just deletions that are causing issues.

Our custom index configuration:

```
<index id="customer_sxa_web_index" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Solr.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Solr" role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement" search:require="solr">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="core">customer_sxa_cpcproducts_web</param>
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
      <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
    </strategies>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
      <crawler type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.SxaItemCrawler, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/customer-Main/customer-Main/Home</Root>
      </crawler>
      <crawler type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.SxaItemCrawler, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/customer-Main/customer-Main/Data/Product Content/</Root>
      </crawler>
    </locations>
    <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
    <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
</index>
```

I would expect deleted (unpublished) items to be removed from the search index. But this is not occuring.

Investigating the logs turns up the following error, I assume this is due to the item not being available in the web database after being unpublished

````
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.SxaItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, Boolean checkLocation)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass94_2.<PerformUpdate>b__0(IndexableInfo info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )```
````